# Electorate badge progress indicator asks to vote for more questions at 0.25 ratio

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, badge-progress

Just a minor detail, but the Electorate badge process indicator on the review page says that my voting ratio is 0.25 and I need to vote on more questions.

[image]

I assume it's because of rounding (the actual ratio is ~0.2456) but it's still a bit misleading. Maybe it could start showing more decimals after 0.245 ("Your voting ratio is 0.246") or have it say "Your voting ratio is *almost* 0.25".

Comment: this bug is effectively obsolete

Answer (score 4):

You *do* need to vote on more questions, because you've only voted on 279. While you meet the 25% criteria, you don't meet the `question votes >= 600` criteria. I guess the placement of the message is a bit misleading, but the statement itself is accurate.

Comment: I'm not saying the statement wouldn't be accurate (*"the actual ratio is 0.2456"*), I'm saying the message could be improved.

Comment: I'm not sure that the calculation doesn't itself round, though. If that's not the case, then yes, I agree.